# Simplifying trigonomic equation of $\sin 2x - \sin x = 0$

Tags: trigonometry

> Solve  $\sin 2x - \sin x = 0$

I know from the double angle formula that

$2\sin x \cos x - \sin x = 0$

What I do not understand is how this simplifies to:

$\sin x(2\cos x - 1) = 0$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have $$2AB-A=0$$ you can just factor out the $A$:
$$A(2B-1)=0$$ If you are skeptical, distribute the $A$ back through. Your problem has $A=\sin(x)$ and $B=\cos(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Use more general method:

If $\sin y=\sin A,$

$y=n\pi+(-1)^nA$ where $n$ is any integer

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin x(2 \cos x -1)=0$$
$\sin x =0$ or $\cos x =\frac 12$

$x=\pi n, n \in \mathbb Z$ or $x=\pm \frac{\pi}{3}+2 \pi k, k \in \mathbb Z$

Answer (score 0):

Hint $\sin(2x)-\sin(x)=2\sin(x/2)\sin(3x/2)$ so either $sin(x/2)=0,sin(3x/2)=0$ thus  $x/2=0+k\pi n,3x/2=0+k\pi n$ and get the solution